# Image resize issue-iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, image-resizing

I have two UIImageviews in my nib and according and one of it is resizing according to the value of UISlider
Code is:-

```
-(IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider*)slider{
    CGFloat scaleFactor=slider.value;

    markerImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
}
```

it is resizing correctly but when I merge these images together by these code

```
UIImage *backImage=backgroundImage.image;
UIImage *markImage=markerImage.image;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backImage.size);

[backImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[markImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I got merged image with original size,
That is the marker image appears in the same dimension in the resultant image
how can i draw the marker image in correct proportion
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `drawAtPoint:`, use `drawInRect:(CGRect)rect`. Also, the slider value needs to be used.

Assuming sliderValue between 0 and 1,

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0, markerImage.size.width*sliderValue, markerImage.size.height*sliderValue);
[markImage drawInRect:rect];
```

**EDIT**

```
CGFloat width = markerImage.size.width*sliderValue;
CGFloat height = markerImage.size.height*sliderValue;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake((markerImage.size.width-width)/2,(markerImage.size.height-height)/2, width, height);
[markImage drawInRect:rect];
```

Comment: this works but my it will place the image in topleft corner iI want this in middle

Comment: I guessed once I give basic idea, you would be able to modify as per your need. Anyhow, I have edited my answer as per your need.